# Return type of fabric pattern method

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am a beginner in .net. I'm trying to understand the fabric pattern method.

I found this code [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3578648/1067943):

```
   public abstract class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Salary = 20000;
    }

}

public class Pilot : Person
{
    public string PilotNumber { get; set; }

    public Pilot()
    {
        this.Salary = 50000;
    }
}

public static class PersonFactory
{
    public static Person CreatePerson(string typeOfPerson)
    {
        switch (typeOfPerson)
        {
            case "Employee":
                return new Employee();
            case "Pilot":
                return new Pilot();
            default:
                return new Employee();
        }
    }
}
```

And to use the factory:

```
Person thePilot = PersonFactory.CreatePerson("Pilot");
    ((Pilot)thePilot).PilotNumber = "123ABC";
```

I can't understand CreatePerson method in this example.

```
public static Person CreatePerson(string typeOfPerson)
    {
        switch (typeOfPerson)
        {
            case "Employee":
                return new Employee();
            case "Pilot":
                return new Pilot();
            default:
                return new Employee();
        }
    }
```

The method returns Person type, but in switch operator as you can see it's creates and returns Pilot() or Employee() instance class.

How can this be that the return type definitions in the method's signature is different from the return type of the function itself.

Comment: Maybe you should read about oop before going into design patterns?

Comment: This is called inheritance. The Pilot and the Employee both inherit from Person, meaning that they are a type of person. Please see the following for a better explanation: [Overview of Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973803.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all of these return types inherit from Person. You can implicitly return a derived class from a function.

```
public class Employee : Person <------ this Employee is inheriting the abstract class 'Person' (but not implementing anything from it)
{
    public Employee()
    {
        this.Salary = 20000;
    }

}
```

e.g. above - the Employee class is actually a Person too since it inherits from the abstract class (it actually doesn't implement anything from the abstract class as there is nothing to implement)

The Person class here is abstract yet it doesn't specify any abstract members - is this just test code?

Answer (score 3):

It's a lot easier when you update your factory method to a generic method. Like this.

```
public static TPerson CreatePerson<TPerson>() where TPerson: Person {
    if (typeof(TPerson) == typeof(Employee)) {
        return new Employee();
    } else if (typeof(TPerson) == typeof(Pilot)) {
        return new Pilot();
    } else {
        return new Employee();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it without any casts:

```
Pilot pilot = PersonFactory.CreatePerson<Pilot>();
pilot.PilotNumber = "123ABC";
```

Comment: I like this even though the generic method does nothing but provide a strongly typed return value +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

Because Pilot inherits from Person.

Answer (score 1):

The Employee and Pilot classes are *subclasses*, or *derived classes* of person.  In OOP this is analagous to an *is a* relationship.  An Employee IS A person, a Pilot IS A person, so it's perfectly legal to return one of those types.  The caller will not know (without using reflection) what *type* of person it got back, and shouldn't care.