# Create a new instance of a type from a variable

Tags: c#, types

Okay, so I have a dictionary of types int and Tile. I have a class called TileManager that I'm designing to return a NEW instance of a certain tile. Right now this is what I have.

```
public class TileManager
{
    private Dictionary<int, Tile> _registeredTiles = new Dictionary<int, Tile>();

    public Tile GetNewTile(int id)
    {
        // Here, I need to return a new instance of the tile at the given key. I want
        // something like this: return new _registeredTiles[id].GetType();
    }
    . . .
}
```

The problem is, I can't just create a new Tile class, because it will be holding different classes other than tiles (it will be holding children of Tile).

Comment: Are you saying you have multiple inheritance of Tile something like SquareTile, CircleTile..etc? or you want to clone the instance stored in _registeredTiles

Comment: You could use a Factory.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578648/type-casting-and-the-factory-pattern

Comment: "holding different classes" implies `Dictionary<int, Type>` (with types restricted to `Tile` and derived ones), but your post shows different declaration `Dictionary<int, Tile>`. Which one is correct?

Comment: By that I meant I have different classes inherited from Tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use `Activator.CreateInstance();`

You can pass it a type and an array of constructor arguments if required:

```
return (Tile)Activator.CreateInstance(_registeredTiles[i].GetType());
```

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I could have sworn I already tried that, but it works! Thanks!