# Make a interface method return an object of type of the class which implemented it

Tags: c#, .net, object, interface

I have searched for an answer to accomplish this, but I haven't found anything: I want an interface's method to return an object of the type of the class which implemented it. For example:

```
interface InterfaceA {
   public static returnValue getObjectFromDatabase(); //What do i need to put as returnValue?
}
```

Then, if I have two classes (for example, ClassA and ClassB) that implement it, I would like to have:

```
ClassA obj1 = ClassA.getObjectFromDatabase(); //return object of class ClassA
ClassB obj2 = ClassB.getObjectFromDatabase(); //return object of class ClassB
```

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Would you be okay with an answer that gives an alternative design to achieve this? Because what you're suggesting isn't a good design and would be difficult to make work well

Comment: If it can help me, sure! :)

Comment: Interfaces can’t have static members, so whatever you are trying to achieve won’t work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you want to do here won't work for two reasons:

1. Interfaces can't have static members
2. Interfaces need to specify the return types of their methods. An interface shouldn't know the types of all the members implementing it, that defeats the point and in many cases would be unachievable.

Moreover, if you did manage to do this, it still wouldn't be good design, because it violates the **single responsibility principle**. You can find plenty of information on this by googling it or looking around this site, but the idea- as indicated by the name- is that a class should only have a single purpose which it is responsible for.

So imagine that your class was, for example, an `Employee` class. That class has a pretty clear responsibility, it should be responsible for holding information and functionality related to an `Employee` in a company. It might have members like `FirstName`, `GivePromotion()`, etc. So it'd be strange to now make this class *also* take responsibility for its own database access.

So how this is achieved would be with another class which is responsible for retrieving objects from the database. One common design pattern for this is the **repository pattern**. You'll also probably want to take advantage of generics. So you repository interface might look like:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetFromDatabase()
}
```

Which you can then implement with a generic repository:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    T GetFromDatabase()
    {
        //Your actual code for database retrieval goes here
    }
}
```

Or, if the database retrieval code is very different for some or all classes, you can implement with a specific repository:

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee>
{
    Employee GetFromDatabase()
    {
        //Your actual code for database retrieval goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use generics:

```
class Program
{
    interface MyInterface<SomeType>
    {
        SomeType getObjectFromDatabase ();
    }

    class A : MyInterface<A> { public A getObjectFromDatabase () { return new A (); } }
    class B : MyInterface<B> { public B getObjectFromDatabase () { return new B (); } }

    class Program2
    {
        static void Main ()
        {
            A a1, a2;
            a1 = new A ();
            a2 = a1.getObjectFromDatabase ();
            B b1, b2;
            b1 = new B ();
            b2 = b1.getObjectFromDatabase ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but then why do you need an instance of `A` just to create `A`? Looks poor design for me.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It doesn't make sense for getting a new object from the database to be an instance member on an existing object.

Comment: I agree, i am attempting to address only the mechanics of the question, not the design issues -- i'd want more context for that..

Comment: Understandable, but since it's static in the original question I'd suggest you're actually introducing new design issues which the asker already realised would be a problem

Comment: I choose the other as answare but this is also good, why an instance of A need to create another instance of A? For example if you have class Car and you want the next model, then car1.getNextModel() will return another car object.

Answer (score 1):

> I want an interface's method to return an object of the type of the class which > implemented it

You seem to miss the point of interfaces: an Interface shouldn't have any knowledge about its implementers. Interface exposes contracts and that's it.

Also, from your example, I can see that you are trying to create a `static` method but interfaces and static are far away from each other. Interfaces are tied with instances, not the type.

Comment: I'm sorry for the errors, but then how i can archive that? for example if i have two different classes, with a method of an interface, that return a object with the same class of who called it?

Comment: @MauroValvano Not exactly what you asked but [Take a look at factory pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3578759/2530848)